# Django User default permission

Tags: django, django-admin, django-permissions

I want to add permissions (view, add, change, delete) to every user, so I add this meta class in each Model

```
class Meta:
   default_permissions = ('add', 'change', 'delete', 'view')
```

but when I log in (with new user) to the Django admin site, the user hasn't got the permission yet. Is my approach wrong?

[image: pics]

EDIT:
I solved this by adding this code to my registration form

```
permission_list = ['view_depot','view_courier','view_client',
                                'add_depot','add_courier','add_client',
                                'change_depot','change_courier','change_client',
                                'delete_depot','delete_courier','delete_client']
permission_list = list(map(lambda x : Permission.objects.get(codename=x), permission_list))
user.user_permissions.add(*permission_list)
```

if anyone know simpler method than feel free to share here

Answer (score 0):

You need to login as Admin in Admin panel and go to users table and find that user and go to down and you will see "Available user permissions"[image]